# Does dieting and workouts mix well?

Tags: diet, upper-body-workout

I recently started to diet so I could loose some weight. My main question is if I diet and do some workouts for targeted areas will I loose fat or not?

I am not looking for muscles  I just want to loose some weight.

So what gives? What should I expect?

Edit: Well about my caloric intake, at breakfast I eat almost 2 cups of oats. For diner and lunch I eat 2 chapattis each with some curry.

About my workout, I wake up at 6 and jog ( actually it's more like I jog the 3/5 of the track and then walk the rest of it and then repeat). After that at 11 I do an abs beginner from the app home workout. At 7 or 8 I do a legs beginner from the app home workout. That's it for me and I am doing this every day.

I want to know what this would result in. Will I lose any weight at all? Will I gain muscle?

Comment: It's not an issue actually... by diet I mean cutting some carbs out, no snacks at all, no soft drinks and stuff. By workout, I do not go to a gym I do workout at home from an app called home workout and I also jog daily in the morning.

Comment: And I think you did not follow I meant what should I expect muscle or weight loss.... muscles, I think probably not but still had to ask.

Comment: Voting to close. All I can tell is that there is no diet, or workout to deal with fat in particular area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you cant "do some workouts for targeted areas" to lose weight in those areas. That is not a thing. Your body will burn fat from wherever the hell it wants to. The only way to lose fat in a specific part of your body is to lose fat in general, everywhere.

If you just want to lose weight, you don't NEED to exercise. You just need to eat less calories than your body expends. If you're eating less calories than your body uses, your body will metabolize its fat stores, and likely also some muscle, to fuel your body. Since you said you don't want muscles, this is a viable option. Just figure out your TDEE and eat less than that to lose weight.

If you want to lose FAT, and want to maintain or even build muscle, than that's an entirely different question, and would require a much more in depth answer that I won't go into here.

As for your question:

> I want to know what this would result in. Will I lose any weight at all? Will I gain muscle?

Most of your exercise is just cardio, so that's just burning calories. I doubt the beginner app home workouts you're doing is enough to promote muscle growth, but it probably will lessen how much muscle your body metabolizes for energy, assuming you're in a caloric deficit. So, as long as the food you are eating is less calories than you're burning throughout the day, including your exercise, you will lose weight and likely won't gain muscle.

Comment: Bang on. An added tip for weight management: Get a food tracker app like myFitnessPal. You can easily lose weight without any gym work just by reducing your caloric intake.